# Javascript mouse scroll delta

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

is there any way to enhance scroll functionality in javascript to force it to scroll vertically to specific element when user uses mouse wheel to scroll?
just want to implement functionality like single page applications have.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried? See [Ask] for a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. You can listen for the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event, which will be triggered when the user scrolls. You can then [prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the window from scrolling and implement whatever you want the page to do on scroll.